# Change WinForms combo box selection with UI Automation

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, user-interface, automation

is it possible to change the selected item in a winforms application using c# UI automation (same logic as UIspy.exe)? I would like to change the selected item to a specific item (I know it's index/position in the list).

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void ActionSelectComboBoxItem(AutomationElement comboBoxElement, int indexToSelect){
        if(comboBoxElement == null)
            throw new Exception("Combo Box not found");

        //Get the all the list items in the ComboBox
        AutomationElementCollection comboboxItem = comboBoxElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));

        //Expand the combobox
        ExpandCollapsePattern expandPattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)comboBoxElement.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern);
        expandPattern.Expand();

        //Index to set in combo box
        AutomationElement itemToSelect = comboboxItem[indexToSelect];

        //Finding the pattern which need to select
        SelectionItemPattern selectPattern = (SelectionItemPattern)itemToSelect.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
        selectPattern.Select();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How can we set the value in a Combo box where the list is generated dynamically.

Like in my case

```
AutomationElementCollection comboboxItem = comboBoxElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
```

comboboxItem.Count is 0

While in the same combobox when i expand it using mouse click it shows all the values.

Comment: Hi Isha, next time if you are posting code, try to make the code as 'code' using the '{}' options.

Answer (score 1):

Further to sizu's answer -
You need to expand the ComboBox BEFORE retrieving the Items.  The items only "exist" as far as 
UIAutomation is concerned when the ComboBox has been expanded.